# Nignx - worker_connections are not enough

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx

I don't know what is going on.
I double value for worker connections but it still return error.

```
server {
server_name xxx.com;

root /var/www/web;
index index.html index.htm index.php;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
location / {
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header   Connection "upgrade";
proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:7777;
}



    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxx.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxx.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name xxx.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri; # managed by Certbot

}
```

Everything is okej with this code?

ERROR:

Firstly was:

```
worker_connections are not enough
worker_connections are not enough
```

Now is

```
27513#0: accept4() failed (24: Too many open files)
27513#0: accept4() failed (24: Too many open files)
27513#0: accept4() failed (24: Too many open files)
27513#0: accept4() failed (24: Too many open files)
```

Comment: Please show the complete `server` block.

Comment: And what is the error you are talking about?

Comment: edited first post

Comment: Try increasing open files liimit:
https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-nginx-too-many-open-files/